# About Hough transform and its plot(with 3 points to plot)

Tags: python, hough-transform

I have a 3 points:

`(1,3) (2,4) (3,5)`

which equation is :

`y = x + 2`

and its

```
slope = 1
intercept = 2
```

After **Hough Transform** and plot,

```
# Hough Transformin in my code
r_axis[i] = x_point * math.cos(th) + y_point * math.sin(th)
```

I got:

[image: plot-hough]

This plot tell me:

```
r = 1
theta = 135 deg (???)
```

But my equation `y = x + 1` tell me

```
theta = 
arctan(slope) ( -pi < tan < +pi ) = 
45 deg
```

The answer should be 45 deg, not 135 deg.

I'm confused

following is my source code:

[code](https://repl.it/repls/FearfulGlisteningQueries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after I think hardly.

The intersection of plot is `theta = 135 deg, r=1.414` not `theta = 135 deg, r=1`

We modify `y = x + 2` to `y - x = 2`

the answer:

```
r = 1.414
theta = 135 deg
```

We substitute to

```
1.414 = y*sin (135 deg) - x*cos(135 deg)
=> 2 = y - x
=> y = x + 2
```

So, code and plot both not problem